# Disposing of the 3em dash exception in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

By default biblatex-chciago replaces repeated authors in the bibliography with a 3em dash, following the Chicago Manual of Style.  However, when the compiled pdf has a page break in between entries by the same author, it insists on repeating the authors name instead of using the dash.  How can I get the package to ignore the existence of the page break and continue using the 3em dash in all cases?

Providing a MWE for this question is not really feasible, *mea culpa*.

Instead, here's a screen clipping to show what I mean, the grey area of course indicating where pg 17 breaks into pg 18. For the entry "Religionis ac scientiae" it should just have another dash instead of repeating "Pope Urban II":
[image: Example repeating author after a page break]

Comment: Adding the option `dashed=false` to your biblatex loading options should turn this feature off. In the 17th edition the use of 3-em dash (---) for multiple works by the same author is actually discouraged (CMOS 14.67) …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` usually does not replace repeated authors with dashed at the beginning of a new page. That way you don't have to go back to the previous page to see the name.

This is done via `biblatex`'s `pagetracker` functionality, which you can completely disable.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, pagetracker=false]{biblatex-chicago}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d}

\vspace{12cm}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that this may have side-effects for citations, where `biblatex-chicago` also checks if a citation is the first on a particular page (which may or may not be desirable in your use case).

If you only want to change the dashes that is also possible, but due to the internal structure of `biblatex-chicago` that is going to be a bit tedious. The dash is printed by eleven different macros, all of which would have to be modified.

Comment: I agree it's a good idea, but some format sticklers don't like the idea of repeating the author on a new page (they are used to word which does not do that).  That's unfortunate that it depends on the pagetracker function, since that is useful for other things, but good to know.

Comment: @Richard As I said, it would be possible, but a pain. Plus, if you deal with people who think the page break does not matter for the dash, they may think the same elsewhere, too.